# fiware-orion freeboard datasource configuration fails

Tags: fiware-orion, freeboard

I´m trying to display a DHT11 sensor (temp & humid) in a freeboard using orion context-broker. The entity has this aspect:

```
<contextElement>
<entityId type="Sala" isPattern="false">
<id>Sala1</id>
</entityId>
<contextAttributeList>
<contextAttribute>
<name>date</name>
<type>string</type>
<contextValue>2016-03-15 11:14:22</contextValue>
</contextAttribute>
<contextAttribute>
<name>humidity</name>
<type>float</type>
<contextValue>35</contextValue>
</contextAttribute>
<contextAttribute>
<name>temperature</name>
<type>float</type>
<contextValue>19</contextValue>
</contextAttribute>
</contextAttributeList>
</contextElement>
```

ORION SERVER is listening but I´m not able to reach the entity with type "Sala" from the freeboard dashboard datasource configuration:

FIWARE dataset configuration

[image]

It fails with 404 - No context element found. I can see it using this text widget:

[image]

Looking into the JS code. I see it adds a "/NGSI10/contextElement" path after the variable cbhost...

```
...
url = "http://"+currentSettings.cbhost+"/NGSI10/queryContext";
...
```

I tried the query using this path with a REST client and couldn't make it work. Do I have to reconfigure my orion server?

I just don´t know how to make it work..

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

--Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when Orion runs in single tenant mode (i.e. without `-multiservice` enabled). Please use the following configuration at FreeBoard:

- Fiware-Service: ' ' (i.e. a whitespace)
- Fiware-ServicePath: '/'

However, you can clone the following Board, already configured to work with your Orion in that way:

https://freeboard.io/board/q7Oe0e

(Side-note: XML is deprecated in Orion and, in fact, next Orion release -1.0.0- will not support it. I'd suggest to stop using it, in favour of JSON).

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the ol' preconfigured Board to work?